# How to Detect collision not depend on the dimension of the 2D picture

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xna

i'm trying to make a small 2d game in xna.

well, Here is the problem:

How to detection of two components were colliding
take a look at the picture below:

[image]
the components above are 2 PNG components  format

I had success to put and moving these components in my game.

now i would like to detect these components when they were colliding. i also have made the collision code, but it all based by dimension of the pictures so if were colliding by pixel no colored, however they are including their dimension between the pictures.(i mean just like collision radius based by dimenssion of pictures)
and they would be considered as collision before collision the between pixel-colored

well, How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Alter your collision code to return the rectangle in which the collision may have occurred, and then use that area to check each alpha value of each pixel. It's called per-pixel collision detection, if you want to look it up in greater detail.

Edit:

```
//Load the texture from the content pipeline
Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Your Texture Name and Directory");

//Convert the 1D array, to a 2D array for accessing data easily (Much easier to do            
Colors[x,y] than Colors[i],because it specifies an easy to read pixel)
Color[,] Colors = TextureTo2DArray(texture);
```

And the TextureTo2DArray() is

```
Color[,] TextureTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
{
    Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height]; //The hard to read,1D array
    texture.GetData(colors1D); //Get the colors and add them to the array

    Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height]; //The new, easy to read 2D array
    for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++) //Convert
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
            colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[x + y * texture.Width];

    return colors2D;
}
```

Comment: Per-pixel collision yes,, it's. But, how can i get the pixel from texture?